# How to pass Arraylist from an activity to Broadcast receiver to another broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-broadcast

i want to pass an arraylist to CheckRunningApplicationReceiver.class(broadcast receiver) from my MainActivity . The  CheckRunningApplicationReceiver.class is called from another broadcast Receiver called StartupReceiver which is called by alarm manager every 5 seconds .Do i need to pass arraylist first to  StartupReceiver and then from there to CheckRunningApplicationReceiver? or can is there any way to pass directly to CheckRunningApplicationReceiver from MainActivity?

StartupReceiver.class

```
public class StartupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

static final String TAG = "SR";

final int startupID = 1111111;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Create AlarmManager from System Services
    final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    try{
            // Create pending intent for CheckRunningApplicationReceiver.class 
            // it will call after each 5 seconds

            Intent i7 = new Intent(context, CheckRunningApplicationReceiver.class);






            PendingIntent ServiceManagementIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                    startupID, i7, 0);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 
                    1000, ServiceManagementIntent);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Exception : "+e);
        }

    }
```

}

CheckRunningApplicationReceiver.class
      public class CheckRunningApplicationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
public final String TAG = "CRAR"; // CheckRunningApplicationReceiver
```

String package_name;
 ConnectivityManager dataManager;

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context aContext, Intent anIntent) {


    dataManager  = (ConnectivityManager)aContext.getSystemService(aContext.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     Method dataMtd = null;
     try {
         dataMtd = ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);
     } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     dataMtd.setAccessible(true);

     try {

        // Using ACTIVITY_SERVICE with getSystemService(String) 
        // to retrieve a ActivityManager for interacting with the global system state.

        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) aContext
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // Return a list of the tasks that are currently running, 
        // with the most recent being first and older ones after in order.
        // Taken 1 inside getRunningTasks method means want to take only 
        // top activity from stack and forgot the olders.

        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> alltasks = am
                .getRunningTasks(1);




        // 
        for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo aTask : alltasks) {





                     // When user on call screen show a alert message





                     if (aTask.topActivity.getClassName().equals("com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList")
                             || aTask.topActivity.getClassName().equals("com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity"))
                     {
                         // When user on Send SMS screen show a alert message
                         try {
                             dataMtd.invoke(dataManager, false);
                         } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }   
                     }







        }

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Throwable caught: "
                    + t.getMessage(), t);
    }

}
```

MainActivity.class

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{   
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
getBaseContext().getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(
                new Intent("StartupReceiver_Manual_Start"));//to start StartupReceiver     

    super.onResume();
}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.javatechig.listapps.AllAppsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


      <activity
        android:name="com.javatechig.listapps.Adblock"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>


    <receiver android:name=".StartupReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="StartupReceiver_Manual_Start" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name = ".CheckRunningApplicationReceiver"/>

   </application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i did was the  user selects particular app,  so i stored these selected  apps in arraylist and stored it using shared preference. the startup broadcast receiver is called every 1 second using alarm manager which inturn calls checkrunningapps broadcast receiver.  here i retrieved the stored arraylist and compare it with  current foreground app and do whatever i want,  like app lock and stuff.  but the problem is every second it retrieves arraylist and checks it. there is bit lag in the app because of this.  I am new to android.  i think my method is wrong .  i also tried to use service  but in service  onstart command  the code executes only once,  so it checks current running app with arraylist only once even though the service is in background indefinitely.  plz tell me the correct approach  to this using  background service.  plz send me the code.  i hv searched  a lot but no luck.  i want the service to  fetch arraylist only once and compare it with current foreground  running app forever.

Answer (score 0):

Use `putParcelableArrayListExtra()` to put the list into the `Intent` and `getParcelableArrayListExtra()` to get the list from the `Intent`.

Yes, you will need to pass this from the `Activity` to the first `BroadcastReceiver` and it can then copy it from the incoming `Intent` to the outgoing `Intent` used to trigger the second `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: thank  u for the answer,  but i saved the arraylist from main activity using shared preferences and retrieved  it from 2nd broadcast receiver directly.